# 1D array generation from dimensionless

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have got an array of dimension (67233,) and need to convert it to (67233,1) but don't know how to proceed? Can anyone suggest a Python solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

Use [reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).
You can do it like so: `arayvar.reshape(67233,1)`